# File Read Error in C

Tags: c, file

This code does not read the full text file.namely,first 30-40 does not read the word. why ?

word source : http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~geoff/classes/hmc.cs070.200009/homework10/simple.dict

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
FILE *fp = fopen("simple.txt","r");

char buf[25];

while (!feof(fp))

{
    fscanf(fp,"%s",buf);
    printf(" %s\n ", buf);

}
fclose(fp);
return 0;

}
```

Comment: "does not read the word"? Huh? Your code skips the first 30-40 lines of text?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included your output.

Comment: Source file called "simple.dict", this code attempts to read "simple.txt".

Comment: Probably,
It is beyond the upper limit of the console buffer. try like as `a.out | more`

Answer (score 1):

There are some fishy things:

1. Check that the file open didn't fail before relying on it.
2. Don't use `feof()` like that, it's not what it's for and it won't work.
3. You only reserve room for `25` characters, that's not very long (your longest word seems to be 14 characters though, so it *should* be fine).
4. You should check the return value of `fscanf()` (in fact, that can be used to replace `feof()`).

Comment: I did 14 characters reserved.This time, the first 30 words read.

Comment: @johnalanson Noooo, don't decrease it! `25` is pretty low as is, and you must have room for the string terminator! `14` won't work.

Comment: does not unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

you can open file and line-by-line read file context like that

```
int main() 
{
    /* Used variables */
    FILE *file;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    /* Open file descriptor */
    file = fopen("simple.txt", "r");
    if(file != NULL)
    {

        /* Line-by-line read file */
        while ((read = getline(&line, &len, file)) != -1) 
        {
            /* Print line */
            printf("%s\n", line);
        }

        /* Close file descriptor and free line */
        fclose(file);
        if (line) free(line);
    }
    else printf("Can not open file\n");

    return 0;
}
```

`getline()` returns -1 when there is no more lines in file